# Start Debugging is disabled in vb.net solution File

Tags: vb.net

I hav I hav a vb.net project in which the start debugging is disabled so can u help me

Answer (score 1):

Can you check in you're in Debug Mode and not in Release Mode.
It's a comboBox at the top of Visual Studio.

Julien